# È corretto dire "idee molto estreme"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, adjectives

Secondo la [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/estremo_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/), l'aggettivo *estremo* proviene di un superlativo:

> **estremo** /e'strɛmo/ (ant. **stremo**) [dal lat. *extremus*, superl. di *exter* o extĕrus* "che sta fuori", trattato anche in ital. come superl. di *esterno*].

Per questa ragione (credo che non si possa dire, per esempio, "molto bellissimo"), vi chiedo: è corretto dire "idee molto estreme"?

---

Per *estremo* come superlativo di *esterno* si veda anche questo [articolo dell'Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/grado-degli-aggettivi_(La-grammatica-italiana)/).

Comment: No, in teoria è un errore perché come dici tu estremo è già un superlativo. Ciò non toglie che nel linguaggio parlato può capitare di sentirlo.

Comment: Superlativo di esterno??

Comment: Sì, @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica.

Comment: @Charo: che vuol dire sì? Che la Treccani dica così ci credo, a meno che tu non abbia trascritto male (e non credo). Magari fa' qualche esempio, io non l'ho mai incontrato.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: E il comparativo sarebbe *esteriore*. Viene dal latino.

Comment: @Charo quindi il punto *estremo* di un segmento non giace su di esso, e se *tocco l'estremo limite* l'ho già superato. Adesso ho capito.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica:  «E se l'infimo grado in sé raccoglie / sì grande lume, quanta è la larghezza / di questa rosa ne l'estreme foglie!» (Dante, *Paradiso* XXX, 115-117: bellissima terzina di questo straordinario canto!). Nota che appare un altro superlativo: *infimo*.

Comment: @Charo: bene, mi spieghi in parole semplici il significato di "estreme foglie" in quel contesto? Perché di testi che usano *estremo* se ne trovano a bizzeffe, il mio problema è capire in quale senso un estremo si possa situare "al di fuori".

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Sono i petali più all'esterno della rosa.

Answer (score 5):

Ho provato a fare una [ricerca con NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pi%C3%B9%20intimo%2Cpi%C3%B9%20estremo&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpi%C3%B9%20intimo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpi%C3%B9%20estremo%3B%2Cc0) con “più estremo” e ”più intimo”. Ci sono parecchi falsi positivi (per esempio una domanda se “si può dire più estremo”). Ma fra i positivi veri trovo questa chicca:

> Per gli ateniesi era il punto più estremo della loro umiliazione.

L'autore è Valerio Massimo Manfredi ([“Akropolis: la grande epopea di Atene”, pagina 109](https://books.google.it/books?id=-g1pAAAAMAAJ&q=%22pi%C3%B9%20estremo%22&dq=%22pi%C3%B9%20estremo%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=Um6JVMCjAa-y7Qa7wYDIBQ&ved=0CEUQ6AEwCA)). In italiano sarebbe

> Era l'estrema umiliazione degli ateniesi.

Brutta letteratura a parte, in aggettivi come *estremo intimo prossimo infimo* la carica di superlativo è meno avvertita, così come *anteriore posteriore esteriore inferiore superiore* vengono poco sentiti come comparativi. Trovi abbastanza facilmente frasi come

> Godono così le Rane del potere di mantenersi a una temperatura un poco più superiore a quella del mezzo ambiente.

e sto citando un [libro del 1851](https://books.google.it/books?id=et0cAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA514&dq=%22poco%20pi%C3%B9%20superiore%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=CnGJVPLWKdPTaI3ogfgC&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA).

Personalmente evito *più estremo*, ma non mi scandalizzo se lo sento o lo leggo; però mi faccio un'opinione dello scrittore anche vedendo come adopera la lingua. Il primo esempio dovrebbe far capire che quello scrittore non è fra i miei preferiti.

Il linguaggio pubblicitario è esente da vincoli, naturalmente: un marchio abbastanza noto è il superlativo del superlativo.

Comment: Un marchio di biancheria? +1 per la “brutta letteratura”, ma anche per tutto il resto.

Comment: @DaG Grazie. Sì indumenti da sotto. ;-)

Comment: Qualche tempo fa lessi un romanzo di Manfredi, ma dopo averlo finito decisi che sarebbe stato il primo e l'ultimo.

Comment: @Charo È successo lo stesso a me, ma forse non sono nemmeno riuscito a finirlo. Recentemente ho preso la stessa decisione dopo aver letto alcuni capitoli di un libro di Ildefonso Falcones.

Comment: @egreg:  Quasi per casualità, ho trovato nell'*Italiano* di Serianni una spiegazione che non sembra essere completamente d'accordo con questa risposta, con esempi di "più estremi" e "le più estreme" tratti di citazioni di Manzoni e di Carlo Levi. Cercherò di riportarlo qui. (A proposito, non sono mai riuscita a leggere un libro di Ildefonso Falcones, e scusa se questo arriva con più di 5 anni di ritardo).

Answer (score 3):

Nel glossario alla fine dell'*Italiano* di Serianni, si può leggere:

> *estremo* è un antico superlativo latino, *EXTREMUS*, ormai non più avvertito come tale in italiano. È dunque possibile adoperare *estremo*, nell'accezione di 'eccessivo, grande, radicale', al comparativo

Alla sezione V.83 se ne trovano questi esempi:

> «Finalmente nuovi casi più generali, più forti, *più estremi*, arrivarono fino a loro» (Manzoni, *I Promessi Sposi*); «Le nuove istituzioni  [...] e anche le *più estreme* e apparentemente rivoluzionarie fra esse» (Levi, *Cristo si è fermato a Eboli*, 222).

La spiegazione del glossario continua così:

> *Estremo*, invece, non ammette gradazioni nel significato di 'ultimo' (*l'estremo saluto*, *essere alle estreme risorse*), che è un significato non graduabile in quanto si riferisce a una posizione determinata in una serie numerica: non si può essere più o meno ultimi, ma solo ultimi o qualcosa d'altro (penultimi, terzultimi, primi, secondi, terzi).

Anche la ristampa del 2011 della Dodicesima edizione del vocabolario Zingarelli riporta:

> **Nota Bene**   **L'aggettivo ‘estremo’ deriva da un superlativo latino, ma nella lingua italiana è percepito spesso come aggettivo di grado positivo; perciò la forma ‘più estremo’ è frequentemente usata**: *fino alle più estreme conseguenze*; *l'ala più estrema di un partito*; *la sventura più estrema* (G. LEOPARDI). **Raro e colloquiale è invece il superlativo ‘estremissimo’**: *un atteggiamento di estremissima prudenza*

Quindi, se quando "estremo" ha il significato di "eccessivo, grande, radicale" si può usare "più estremo", deduco che "molto estremo" sia anche accettabile e, dunque, che l'espressione "idee molto estreme" sia pure ammissibile.

Comment: E hai ragione, anche quando dici che estremo non è più avvertito come superlativo.

Comment: Questo è un altro interessantissimo caso in cui si capisce che l’etimologia serve solo a capire da dove venga una parola, ma non dove sia o dove stia andando :-)

Answer (score 0):

Suona piuttosto bruttino. Mi sembra accettabile solamente in un contesto fortemente colloquiale oppure con licenza poetica.

Answer (score 0):

'idee molto estreme' è una forma che certamente lascia sconcertati tanto è brutta.

Sconsiglio di usarla e, se proprio si deve affermare il concetto che sottende, io userei 'idee *davvero* / *particolarmente* estreme' oppure — ed è equivalente in taluni contesti — 'idee *estremistiche*'.